# Label is nil in custom controller class

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

```
// This is in ViewController.swift

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var oneLabel: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()    
      oneLabel.stringValue = "All is well"  // Here it works
      //...
    }
}

// Separate Swift code file

import Cocoa

import Foundation

var si = Simulate()

class Simulate: NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var aLabel: NSTextField!

  func simulationManager() -> Bool {

    var ni: Int
    var breakPoint = false  
    rd.simStatus = .Running

    do {
      if rd.rchIndex >= ld.NodeCount(.Reach) {  
        if InterStepConvergence() {

          NextTimeStep()

          if aLabel != nil {  // This is always false
            aLabel.stringValue = String(rd.elapsedSec)
          }
          else {
            println("Label is nil")
          }
          //...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to set up a custom controller to update the interface while a
simulation is running.  I need to show the status of the simulation.  The simulation runs in a separate thread, but even if I do it in the main thread, same problem as described below.

The label text can be changed if I do it in the ViewController class as above.
But if I try to modify the text on the label in the Simulate class the label
is always nil and so it doesn't work.  But the code compiles OK.  What am I missing here such that the label is always nil in the Simulate class?  Thanks much, in advance.

Comment: Are you sure setup `aLabel` outlet properly? Also are you sure call `simulationManager()` after `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: can i see your source code via github?